# We want to know Launching dates of Area52

Tags: discussion, area-51

I and my aliens friends want to know dates. We do not want details about the platform. Shhh... we are planning an invasion and this information is important to our strategy. .. nah.. I'm just joking.

Now seriously, dates. 2015? 2051?

[image]

Comment: 6 to 8 weeks?  Maybe longer.

Comment: As an alien, I approve of this question.